# How do I compile multiple file c++ programs for intel edison?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, intel-edison

I have tried a makefile in addition to command line compilation.

here is the result of command line compilation

```
neweddy:~/testdir/realworld$ g++ main.cpp lights.cpp 
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `red'
/tmp/cco6q58J.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `blue'
/tmp/cco6q58J.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `white'
/tmp/cco6q58J.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `dutyRed'
/tmp/cco6q58J.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `dutyBlue'
/tmp/cco6q58J.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o:(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `dutyWhite'
/tmp/cco6q58J.o:(.data+0x8): first defined here
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::Pwm(int, int, bool)':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmC2Eiib[_ZN4mraa3PwmC5Eiib]+0x1b): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_init'
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmC2Eiib[_ZN4mraa3PwmC5Eiib]+0x34): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_init_raw'
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmC2Eiib[_ZN4mraa3PwmC5Eiib]+0xd1): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_owner'
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::~Pwm()':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmD2Ev[_ZN4mraa3PwmD5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_close'
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::enable(bool)':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb[_ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb]+0x23): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_enable'
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb[_ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb]+0x3a): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_enable'
/tmp/ccASBZtK.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::config_ms(int, float)':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3Pwm9config_msEif[_ZN4mraa3Pwm9config_msEif]+0x1d): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_config_ms'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is the result of makefile compilation

```
neweddy:~/testdir/realworld$ make
g++ -Wall -c main.cpp
g++ -Wall -c lights.cpp
g++ -Wall -o realworld main.o lights.o
lights.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `red'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
lights.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `blue'
main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
lights.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `white'
main.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
lights.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `dutyRed'
main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
lights.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `dutyBlue'
main.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here
lights.o:(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `dutyWhite'
main.o:(.data+0x8): first defined here
lights.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::Pwm(int, int, bool)':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmC2Eiib[_ZN4mraa3PwmC5Eiib]+0x1b): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_init'
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmC2Eiib[_ZN4mraa3PwmC5Eiib]+0x34): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_init_raw'
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmC2Eiib[_ZN4mraa3PwmC5Eiib]+0xd1): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_owner'
lights.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::~Pwm()':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3PwmD2Ev[_ZN4mraa3PwmD5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_close'
lights.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::enable(bool)':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb[_ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb]+0x23): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_enable'
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb[_ZN4mraa3Pwm6enableEb]+0x3a): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_enable'
lights.o: In function `mraa::Pwm::config_ms(int, float)':
lights.cpp:(.text._ZN4mraa3Pwm9config_msEif[_ZN4mraa3Pwm9config_msEif]+0x1d): undefined reference to `mraa_pwm_config_ms'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:2: recipe for target 'realworld' failed
make: *** [realworld] Error 1
```

and here is my makefile

```
realworld: main.o lights.o
    g++ -Wall -o realworld main.o lights.o

main.o: main.cpp lights.h
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp

lights.o: lights.cpp lights.h
    g++ -Wall -c lights.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o
```

Anyone have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are the #include

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "lights.h"


int initSocket();

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    char recBuff[255];
    char sendBuff[255];
    bzero(recBuff, sizeof(recBuff));
    bzero(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff));

    initLights();

    //int n = 0;
    int sock, clientsock;
    int running = 1;

    sock = initSocket();
    while(running){
        clientsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)NULL,NULL);
        printf("Got client\n");
        read(clientsock,recBuff,255);
        //memcpy(&dutyRed, recBuff, sizeof(float));
        //printf("red %f\n", dutyRed);
        running = 0;
    }

    closeLights();
}

int initSocket(){
    int sockfd, portno;
    portno = 31002;
    int yes = 1;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1){
        perror("setsockopt\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        perror("error on bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sockfd,5);
    printf("waiting for connection...\n");
    return sockfd;
}
```

lights.cpp

```
#include "lights.h"

int initLights(){
    red = new mraa::Pwm(3);
    if (red == NULL) {
        return MRAA_ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    blue = new mraa::Pwm(5);
    if (blue == NULL) {
        return MRAA_ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    white = new mraa::Pwm(6);
    if (white == NULL) {
        return MRAA_ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    }
    return 0;
}

void setLights(float dutyRed, float dutyBlue, float dutyWhite){
    red->enable(true);
    blue->enable(true);
    white->enable(true);

    red->config_ms(1, dutyRed);
    blue->config_ms(1, dutyBlue);
    white->config_ms(1, dutyWhite);
}

void closeLights(){
    delete red;
    delete blue;
    delete white;
}
```

lights.h

```
#ifndef LIGHTS_H
#define LIGHTS_H

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include "mraa.hpp"

mraa::Pwm* red;
mraa::Pwm* blue;
mraa::Pwm* white;


float dutyRed = 0.5;
float dutyBlue = 0.5;
float dutyWhite = 0.5;

int initLights();
void setLights(float,float,float);
void closeLights();

#endif
```

Comment: BTW, this is not specific to Intel Edison.

Comment: There's also no way to know without seeing lights.cpp, main.cpp, and any non-standard headers they include. (Where are red, blue, white, dutyred, dutyBlue,  dutyWhite, mraa_pwm_init, mraa_pwm_init_raw, mraa_pwm_owner, mraa_pwm_close, mraa_pwm_enable and mraa_pwm_config_ms declared and defined?)

Comment: This has nothing to do with your makefile or how you're invoking the compiler.  Your code is wrong.

Comment: I've added my source files, I must be doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: You have defined global variables in a header, so every file that includes the header gets another copy of those variables, so when you link the files together there are multiple definitions.